# How to make data processing out of blockchain?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, oracles, chainlink

Is it possible to send data out of chain, process it and feed into smart contract without using centralized services? My goal is to make data processing large data decentralize (without using web2).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The hard part is to define a suitable protocol. You can get inspiration in oracles protocols.

Comment: Thank you for responding.
Decentralized oracles can provide connectivity to the "external" world. I need to find some blockchain like service to keep entire data processing life cycle in web3 theme (without using centralized servers). Is there some decentralized solutions specially designed to process data to extend the capabilities of the conventional blockchains (e.g. making cost effective calculations)?

Answer (score 0):

Hello [skock](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/112470/skock)

This is the oracle concept!

Chainlink is a decentralized network with solutions to connect smart contracts with the off-chain world

Take a look in the [Documentation](https://docs.chain.link/), it has a lot of examples.